# How to force a new seed without any migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tfs

For a changeset I need to populate a table with some seed values.

But... I have no new migration in this changeset. The seed is normally invoked after the last migration has been done.

How can I force the build to seed after deploy ?

(using VS2013, TFS 2012 SP1, EF 5.0, MVC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a migration. [The Migrations Seed method runs anytime Update-Database is used.](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/)

`Update-Database -ConnectionString "Data Source=etc"`

Comment: Note to all - you can just do `Update-Database` and it will seed.